# Possible to show a subset of the points using one datalayer with mapbox-gl-js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have datalayer consisting of points/ markers in Mapbox-gl-js. When I would like to split my points into categories I can use data-styling, for example like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8vnsbpqf/5/):

```
"source-layer": "sf2010",
    "paint": {
        "circle-radius": {
            "base": 1.75,
            "stops": [[12, 2], [22, 180]]
        },
        "circle-color": {
          property: 'ethnicity',
          type: 'categorical',
          stops: [
            ['White', "#fbb03b"], 
            ['Black', '#223b53'], 
            ['Hispanic', '#e55e5e'], 
            ['Asian', '#3bb2d0'], 
            ['Other', '#ccc']]
        }
```

It seems, using one datalayer, all points (possibly with different category-stylings) will be included on the map. I can style a category of points to not show by giving it a circle-radius of zero, but then it still reacts to clicks etc. Or is there a way to really present a subset of the points using one datalayer?

Comment: you can use a [`filter`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-filter) to filter out the points you do not want to show or use new [expressions](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions) syntax to make a [conditional expression](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Molly suggested, you want a filter:

```
    "source-layer": "sf2010",
    "paint": {
        "circle-radius": {
            "base": 1.75,
            "stops": [[12, 2], [22, 180]]
        },
        "circle-color": {
          property: 'ethnicity',
          type: 'categorical',
          stops: [
            ['White', "#fbb03b"], 
            ['Black', '#223b53'], 
            ['Hispanic', '#e55e5e'], 
            ['Asian', '#3bb2d0'], 
            ['Other', '#ccc']]
        }
   }, 
   "filter": ['!==', 'ethnicity','Martian']
```